# UIDatePicker not showing up in static tableView on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have a table view showing up in a modal with a couple of static cells that show a start date and end date.

When I click on them, I want the UIDatePicker to show up. Currently, nothing happens when I click on the row. What am I missing?

Here's my didSelectRowAtIndexPath :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.pickerView.date = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:selectedCell.detailTextLabel.text];

    //  check if date picker already on screen
    if (self.pickerView.superview == nil) {
        [self.view.window addSubview:self.pickerView];

        // size up the picker view to fit our screen and compute animation
        //
        //compute the start frame
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        CGSize pickerSize = [self.pickerView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 
                                       screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height, 
                                       pickerSize.width, 
                                       pickerSize.height
                                       );
        self.pickerView.frame = startRect;

        //computer end frame
        CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 
                                       screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height, 
                                       pickerSize.width, 
                                       pickerSize.height
                                       );
        // start the slide up animation
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

            // we need to perform some post operations after the animation is complete
            [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

            self.pickerView.frame = pickerRect;

            // shrink the table vertical size to make room for the date picker
            CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.frame;
            newFrame.size.height -= self.pickerView.frame.size.height;
            self.tableView.frame = newFrame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        // add the "Done" button to the nav bar
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton;
    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake. I had the pickerView property set as weak instead of strong in my header file:

this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView;
```

should actually be this:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView;
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in this answer. You had weak both times :P